# Can I use VBA to "pass" a password to an external database connection in Excel?

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I am trying to use VBA to hide the password for a data connection I have set up in an Excel sheet.   Since Excel stores passwords to external data sources in plain text, I wanted to have VBA call the refresh of the table and supply the password.   I recorded a macro of my refreshing the table and entering the password, but to my dismay, it seems it omitted the password part...which was the only part I needed.

```
Sheets("RAW").Select
Range("R16").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

I am unable to find any solutions to this online.  I am vaguely aware that a DB connection can be set up directly through VBA, but a) there are a lot of pivots and whatnot built off of the data table and b) I'm not sure I understand DB's enough to figure all that out.   Does anyone know if there is any way to have VBA "pass" the password to an external data connection?

Comment: You'll probably have to update the connection string on the querytable to include the password, refresh, and then remove the password from the connection string.  Brief research showed that when the password is entered, it is saved in the connection string so that you won't have to enter it in later.

Comment: Apparently if you recreate the database connection, there is a small box to 'remember the password'. Some other people discuss it on this here:
http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/using-ms-excel-to-run-a-query-vba-to-enter-password-2301150
You can also edit the connection string (which should be saved externally), to include the password. It's usually recommended to have a 'read-only' user for the database, to use in applications like these. That way if someone takes/cracks the password, its no big deal.

Comment: I'm familiar with the checkbox.  Was hoping to find a way that would allow me to distribute the sheet to a few people without giving out my password.   I only have read access so I'm not sure what harm would come from them having my password,  but still,  I would prefer to keep it secure. I didn't think about VBA to rewrite the connection strong each time.   Kind of easy to "hack", but in the application I intend,  I highly doubt anyone would be trying.   I'll have to test it when I have a chance to see if it can be done that way.   Thanks

Comment: I checked and it does appear that I can use VBA code to update.  I appreciate the help.   If either of you care to post it as an "answer",  I would gladly accept it so you can get credit for the answer and the question would not sit as "unanswered" when you have, in fact, already answered the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was indeed to update the connection string in VBA, as suggested by OpiesDad and KrisB.