# Refreshing multiple data connections simultaneously in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook that has 10 sheets.

Each sheet is connected to [the same] Oracle database, and each sheet issues a different SQL query that has been pasted into the "Definition".

The database requires a sign in. So when I want to refresh these 10 sheets, I hit "Refresh All", and the following sequence commences:

1. Refresh All
2. Sign into database
3. Issues SQL query
4. Moves to next tab
5. Repeat

The process takes nearly two hours.

My question is: How can I enter in my credentials *one time* and have all 10 kick off simultaneously? It is an ODBC connection.

Please let me know what other information is needed. I can use VBA if needed.

Comment: Are you concerned about the security risks of saving your password into the workbook?

Comment: Not at all. This is completely maintained on my desktop, so no biggie. Worst case, I could make a userform to capture that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the password in the data connection or do this inside VBA in the workbook. Please see this similar question [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271322/refresh-a-connection-in-excel-to-sql-server-with-password-using-vba)

Comment: Even if I save the password, and then click "Refresh All", do all ten queries execute simultaneously? Or do they still occur sequentially?

Comment: They will all occur sequentially but you will not be required to enter your password for reach individual one if the password is saved for the specific connection, it will all happen automatically. I have done this using both VBA and save passwords, neither way was I able to have multiple data sources refresh in parallel if that is what you are referring to.