# Refresh all but input pwd once

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I have an excel file with roughli 25 oracle connections that I have to refresh. Each one prompts a usn and password input. I would like a vba that prompts for a usn and password once and inputs it in all following prompts.

I have been searching for a way to do this but can not find a suitable solution.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why isn't this suitable... https://community.oracle.com/thread/679324  ??

Comment: Hi, if I am not mistaken this will execute a query written directly in the vba. I have all my connections and sql written already but not through vba (i am not good at vba). The thing I want is the same as a refresh all button that remembers the user name and password of the user and inserts them when prompted.

Comment: Ok, then why isn't this suitable... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271322/refresh-a-connection-in-excel-to-sql-server-with-password-using-vba  ???

Comment: Because I can't have people without the proper credentials updating the connections...

Comment: Maybe this will help. It could be a button to refresh all. When pressed - popup to insert oracle username and password - refresh all (uses the inputed credentials to refresh all)

Comment: You haven't answered my question in any relevant or meaningful way.  If there is a VBA prompt for a username and password, like the one in you said you want, then VBA must send that information to the server.  How is the second link unsuitable when it shows a way to send the username and password to the server?  Are we failing to communicate or did you think you were going to find a copy and paste solution to your problem?

Comment: The way I understood the info on the second link was to go under connection properties and select the remember password for each connection. As far as I know this remembers the username and password so next time the connection refreshes without prompting for anything. So anyone can open the file click refresh all and its done. I am completely new to vba so I could be missing something. First of all I would like to know if this is even possible.

Comment: That was helpful feedback, thank you for the explanation.  This comment will continue in the answer section...

Answer (score 0):

> "First of all I would like to know if this is even possible."

In short, yes   It all comes down to the connection string.  How you go about creating and using that string is up to your requirements and your imagination.

> "I have been searching for a way to do this but can not find a suitable solution."

Anecdotal evidence suggests a person suffering from this condition failed to do one it more of the following:

- ask the right question
- recognize the right answer
- to have patience or persistence
- overcome laziness
- access Google

But seriously, I don't know what to tell you, the answer is in comments of the the second link I gave you,   Specifically, the third and fourth comment.  The third points vaguely toward the connection string and the forth takes you to more helpful commentary.

- [Refresh a connection in Excel to SQL Server (with password) using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271322/refresh-a-connection-in-excel-to-sql-server-with-password-using-vba)
- [Can I use VBA to "pass" a password to an external database connection in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879899/can-i-use-vba-to-pass-a-password-to-an-external-database-connection-in-excel)

Comment: Thank you. I will have another look at it.

Comment: @MP90 You're welcome, happy to help.  I hope you decide to give it a shot, hate to think of anyone logging in 25 times like that